# Webservice Contract First Visual Studio Addin 2008: did someone succeed to install?

Tags: visual-studio

I've tried to install this
http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/wscf

it seems I have to download the vs2005 version first and then update with a file for vs2008.

But the addin failed to install as for me.

Did someone achieve to do so with VS 2008 ?

Comment: if you are still having trouble, try the latest version.  I got it setup on VS2010 no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It looks like it is needed to have VS 2K5 before being able to use this add-in.
I guess the setup for VS 2005 tries to add a toolbar or some menu items, so it launches VS 2005, which of course fails if you don't have it.

Instead of preparing a setup program for VS 2008, the author just provides an updated .addin while for it. 
Maybe it is enough to extract the files from the .msi (see [the back room tech](http://thebackroomtech.com/2009/05/20/the-best-msi-extractor/) for a link) and then install the .addin file from the zip of the "2008 version".

If you succeed in doing this with the msi, put then this .addin file in a directory where VS 2008 looks for it (see the list in Tools / options / Environment / Addins Macro security).
Inside the .addin, there is the path to the add-in itself, which must be of course adapted.